# Most efficient way to have many inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's kind of hard to describe what exactly I am looking for here, but I can provide an example.
Let's say I have a series of inputs, like for the number row, I have an input for One, and Two and Three, etc. I want to set something to happen when I press these keys, so like

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("One"))
        {
            doThing1();
        }
         if(Input.GetButton("Two"))
        {
            doThing2();
        }
     //and so on and so on
    }
```

I am not that experienced with Unity or C# so I always like to ask because there may be a chance that there is something that makes this process a lot simpler, instead of having 10 or more if statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a more performant way to detect infrequently used input than Update()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857803/1092820)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do a for Loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
 {
     if ( Input.GetKeyDown( "" + i ) )
     {
         print(i);
     }
 }
```

Or get the name of the button pressed:

```
string name = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;

...

switch (name) {
   case KeyCode.Alpha1.ToString() : break;
   case KeyCode.Alpha2.ToString() : break;
   case KeyCode.Alpha3.ToString() : break;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Efficient to type, yes.  Efficient to run, hell no!

Comment: @Immersive, never said it was.